# Are Titles Proper Nouns

Tags: nouns, proper-nouns

I have always believed titles to be proper nouns, so in this question I stated it as an answer
["Why We Listen to Music" versus "Why Do We Listen to Music" in title](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/166073/why-we-listen-to-music-versus-why-do-we-listen-to-music-in-title/166074?noredirect=1#comment331995_166074)

Somebody has been insisting in comments they are not proper nouns, but as it is a comment and not a proper answer there hasn't been room to expand.

Here is my research:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun

> Current linguistics makes a distinction between proper nouns and
>   proper names; but this distinction is not universally observed
>
> By this strict distinction, because the term noun is used for a class
>   of single words (tree, beauty), only single-word proper names are
>   proper nouns: Peter and Africa are both proper names and proper nouns;
>   but Peter the Great and South Africa, while they are proper names, are
>   not proper nouns.

So some people make a distinction between proper nouns and names, but not everyone does. The name of an article is it's name, so some linguists call these proper names, others call them proper nouns.

Comment: Shouldn't any noun be applicable individually to *multiple* members of the class of entity for which that noun stands?  With respect to names, we do not say "a *For Whom the Bell Tolls*" though we do say *Is there a 'Mary' here?*  In a book of recipes, what label would you apply to *Nana's Pound Cake*?

Comment: You  provide no evidence for "linguists who call the name of an article a proper name". I think that is entirely misguided.

Comment: @Lambie please can you provide a full answer please, as you have so much to say on this subject.

Comment: I think this is a trivial terminological distinction that might interest *some* "linguists", but is of no real consequence to anyone learning English. And since it's not a well-recognised distinction, any answers here would be essentially *opinions* anyway, so the question itself is POB. For what it's worth, I'm with Merriam Webster, where the entry for [***proper noun***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proper%20noun) says *...called also **proper name***.

Comment: ([**Collins**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/proper-noun) dictionary also says *proper name* is simply an alternative for *proper **noun***.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Those definitions just reflect the older, less theoretically sound analyses that are still in use by some, but that doesn't mean they're *valid* analyses or that the terminological distinction doesn't communicate something useful about how words and phrases are put together.  There's a reason the distinction is made these days.

Comment: @snailboat♦: I *strongly* disagree (particularly with the idea that mine, MW's, Collins position reflects "older, less theoretically sound analyses"), but I must admit I'm rather surprised that the relevant Wikipedia page (which is just about the *only* online resource I could easily find referring to this distinction) isn't specifically flagged up as "contains multiple issues". But even if there are a few [linguists? grammarians?] who think it's a *useful* distinction, I can't see how it's relevant to people who want to learn English. It's not even a language-specific concept.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Dictionaries register usage, so it's no surprise they contain definitions pertaining to older analyses (after all, some time needs to pass in order for people to start using new, better ones). The newer analyses (I'm mainly talking about the 2002 one, the bits of which I've read, laid out in CGEL) have been offered because they analyze the grammar of such phrases better, i.e. more consistently, cogently, etc. It becomes obvious why such an analysis is needed once you read it; it also becomes obvious why the older ("traditional") ones are **lacking**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't mean to sound rude, but in order for you to disagree, you'd have to have read both of them and understood them, neither of which I suspect you've done. In the context of linguistics, yes, they are inferior. That's not to say older analyses have no value – quite the opposite; most of what the traditional analyses offer has been copied over, and new analyses try to cling to the previous nomenclature wherever they can in order to avoid back-incompatibility.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The Wikipedia article clearly says it's not universally observed, and that's what snailboat has tried to tell you: there are still those who adhere to the traditional grammar **mainly because** they haven't been taught the new one, or for their needs (think elementary, high schools) it's not required. I wholeheartedly agree this isn't an issue a learner should concern themselves with, and is, as you said, a trivial terminological distinction from the perspective of someone who doesn't actually care about how English works under the hood.

Comment: But why, then, if we already have these new analyses that are actually better, *why* would we tell the students the Earth is flat when we can call it a ball, or whatever? *Especially* when someone is asking about that exact distinction. We can tell them, yes, some people still think it's flat, and for your Newton's laws it should all work out, but just so you know, it's actually a ball.

Comment: As the comments suggest, this is a subject of some debate among linguists.  While the newer analyses suggest you may be right and titles are *not* considered *proper nouns*, in the end it's a *trivial* distinction.  The real question is **why this matters to you**, and **how it affects your learning of English**.  I'm going to recommend this question be closed as opinion-based, and probably better addressed on ELU or a Linguistics forum.

Comment: @Andrew I stated in my question why it matters to me, i was told they weren't I believed they are, I wanted an answer from the nay sayer why they weren't. They simply added a comment here and gave no further information.

Comment: @WendyG  I think you have to accept that there is no **official** answer -- that it's simply a matter of opinion.  If you want to understand all the arguments for and against, I suggest reading the referenced documents.

Answer (score 1):

A noun can appear where a object is expected.  This works with proper nouns/names, so the answer to your question appears to be yes.

> I watched Peter yesterday.
>
> I watched Peter Smith yesterday.
>
> I watched Why Do We Listen to Music yesterday.

With movie titles that are more than a few words, it can be said like this to avoid confusion, of course:

> I watched the movie Why Do We Listen To Music yesterday.

As far as whether it's worthwhile to make the distinction between proper nouns and names - I think the below are examples of proper nouns that aren't names:

> When do you want the assignment done, Professor?
>
> Yes, Lord, I will complete the task.
>
> I love you, Mom.